# Letter spacing is too large in UILabel on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, interface-builder, ios10

I got a problem that text in UILabel looks good on iOS 9 but too ugly on iOS 10, letter spacing is too large. Let's see images below for detail.

On iOS 9:

[image]

On iOS 10:

[image]

And this is how I configure it:

[image]

Please advise me to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:
I just found in codebase that UILabel text alignment is NSTextAlignmentJustified. I changed to NSTextAlignmentLeft and it works now. Thank all of you for your support!

Comment: text you shown is Software Development, but there it is reflecting as Software and Hardware, Check it.

Comment: try to enable Tighten Letter Spacing in Label's property.

Comment: @R.Mohan Yes, Software Development is just sample text.

Comment: @KKRocks Thanks, I tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change Alignment from **left align to center align.**

See image

[image]